# The functionalities are working locally, but once I host this message display for some of the pages

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, amazon-s3

The functions are working locally, but once I host this message display for some of the pages

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myshelf'@'54.235.58.92' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1056)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:894)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3808)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2032)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor71.newInstance(Unknown Source
```

i am trying to create a new catalog and add the picture of the cover to S3 bucket

String awsAccessKey = "";
        String awsSecretKey = "";

```
    String name_val="";
    String desc_val="";

//  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    //String username = (String) session.getAttribute("user_session");
    //String clubfield=(String) session.getAttribute("res_ses");*/
//  int att_id=0;
    //String[] ccode;
    String fieldname ="",fieldvalue="",fieldname1="" ,fieldvalue2="",fieldname2="",fieldvalue1="" ,fieldvalue3="",fieldname3="";
    String categori="" ;
    String category="" ;
    String catalog="" ;
    String nb="" ;

//  String cclub="";
    Connection con = null;
    // ccode = clubfield.split("-");
    // cclub=ccode[0];
     String filetit="";
     String filename="";
     String test="";
     int s=0;
    // System.out.println("club code"+cclub);
    try{
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = 
        new AWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials);
    S3Bucket[] myBuckets = s3Service.listAllBuckets();
    System.out.println("How many buckets to I have in S3? " + myBuckets.length);


        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {


                    fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    if(fieldname.equals("catalog")){
                        name_val=item.getString();
                    }
                    if(fieldname.equals("catalog")){
                        catalog=item.getString();
                        System.out.println(catalog);
                    }
                    if(fieldname.equals("desc")){
                        desc_val=item.getString();
                    }

                    if(fieldname.equals("cat")){
                        category=item.getString();
                        System.out.println(category);

                    }
                    if(fieldname.equals("nb")){
                        nb=item.getString();
                        System.out.println(nb);

                    }
                fieldvalue = item.getString();
                fieldname1 = item.getFieldName();
              System.out.println("fieldname1"+fieldname1);
                fieldvalue1 = item.getString();
                fieldname2 = item.getFieldName();
                fieldvalue2 = item.getString();
                System.out.println("fieldname1"+ fieldvalue);


                System.out.println("fieldname"+fieldname+ "--"+fieldvalue);
                   System.out.println(fieldname1+ "--"+fieldvalue1);
                   System.out.println(fieldname3+ "--"+fieldvalue3);



               filetit=fieldvalue+"/"+filename;
            } else {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").

                filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
               System.out.println("filename come on come on--"+filename);
                if(!filename.equals(""))
                { InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
              //  System.out.println(att_id+"/"+cclub+"_clubcode.jpg");
                //filetit= request.getParameter("file");
                System.out.println(  filename );
                S3Object s3obj = new S3Object("myshelf/brand/"+filename);
                s3obj.setDataInputStream(filecontent);
                s3Service.putObject("foofystestbucket", s3obj);
                }

            }           
        }
```

i think i have the problem in this part because i am using different way to connect to the database 
public class Connect {

```
private java.sql.Connection conn=null;


public Connect () {}


public boolean dbConnect(){
boolean ok = false;              
try {
         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         }
         catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){                                        
            ok = false;
         }
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myshelf?useServerPrepStmts=false", "myshelf", "myshelffoofysPASS");
       // conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://174.129.206.66:3306/myshelf","myshelf","myshelffoofysPASS");
        // conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/myshelf","root","");

         ok = true;
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
         ok = false;
    }
return ok;
}


    public static Connection DbConn() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     //  return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://174.129.206.66/myshelf","myshelf","myshelffoofysAPI");  
        //return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/myshelf","root","");
         return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myshelf?useServerPrepStmts=false", "myshelf", "myshelffoofysAPI");
        }




public java.sql.Connection getConn() {
return conn;
}
```

}

Comment: For *some* pages only? It seems that your authentication data is not complete (or it differs between the pages). Please show the code.

Comment: the problem is for some pqge i can insert to the data base and for other fonctionalitiesn,they are working but when i check the data base nothing happend

Comment: What does S3 have to do with MySQL?

Comment: is it a problem if i am using to diffrent way to connect to the Database ?